# broken kqueue warning when running Crystal on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos-sierra, kqueue, crystal-lang

I decided to try playing with Crystal to check its speed and compatibility relative to Ruby.  I downloaded the pre-built .pkg installer to my macOS Sierra system.  My small test programs appear to run, but all produce the following message:

```
$ crystal --version
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
Crystal 0.19.4 [7f82f79] (2016-10-07)
$
```

I suspect an incompatibility with Sierra, or an out-of-date or missing library.  Does anybody know what the fix is?  It's annoying, but is it also potentially hazardous?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

try reinstalling libevent

```
brew update
brew reinstall libevent
brew reinstall crystal-lang
```

This is the link that helped me out https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/2869

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not a fan of homebrew, and was using the pre-built crystal binary to avoid having to do a brew-based install.